# python3 modifying rows in a dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, conditional-statements, rows

I have a dataframe something like

```
A    B      C
1    4      x
2    8      y
3    7      z
4    12     y
5    10     b
```

i need to modify column B based on condition something like

```
if B <= 5 then B = 1
if B > 5 and B <= 10 then B = 2
if B > 10 and B < 15 then B = 3
```

so that my dataframe becomes

```
A    B      C
1    1      x
2    2      y
3    2      z
4    3      y
5    2      b
```

i am okay if I have to add a new column first and then drop column B. Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `apply` function to implement this.

```
def check(row):
    if (row['B']) <= 5:
        return 1
    elif (row['B'] > 5) and (row['B'] <= 10):
        return 2
    elif (row['B'] > 10) and (row['B'] <= 15):
        return 3
```

These would apply the function to each row and then you can perform the checks.

```
df['B'] = df.apply(check, axis = 1)
```

Then the resulting DF would look like:

```
A    B      C
1    1      x
2    2      y
3    2      z
4    3      y
5    2      b
```

More documentation available [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).